# Need suggestions for system wide profiler for an embedded linux device

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, system-profile

I would like to profile my embedded linux device for various actions (e.g. touch input on screen, flip a page in a news reading app etc). But the requirement is that the profiler should generate information for the entire software stack on the device both user space and kernel space. It would be best if the profiler does not include a significant overhead for logging purposes as memory and resources are very limited on the embedded linux device.

Any suggestions ?